# How to Change Weight Unit in Magento 2 for Migrated Products

Tags: magento2, data-migration, product-weight, size-weight-units

I have recently migrated my store from OpenCart. I have around 2700+ products. In OpenCart Grams as unit was available but not available in Magento 2. Is there any non-programing option available to Add/change weight unit in magento2. My current magento version is 2.2.6.

Converting and changing all 2700+ product weight manually is not an easy option.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Niraj

Answer (score 0):

By default, the weight is abstract in Magento. It does not have a measuring unit. You can consider it what you want.

There are some shipping methods like UPS where you can state the measuring unit, but this does not autodetect anything. You are just telling UPS that you use LBS or KG, but you still have to be careful at what you input in for the products.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use UPS with Magento as everyone is giving the example of UPS. 
I am already using Delhivery and we do have weight based shipping charges.